# WSDL with duplicate names -- how to force Java Class names

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

**Background:**
We are developing an application that communicates with several 3rd party webservices.
Sadly, one of them has defined a WSDL file using poor naming conventions.
The same names are often re-used for a response element, and the complexType that it employs. The code snipped below shows one such occurrence as an example:

```
  <s:element name="Reset_PasswordResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Reset_PasswordResult" type="tns:ResetPasswordResponse" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:complexType name="ResetPasswordResponse">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="tns:BaseResponse" />
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
```

We use Maven cxf codegen plugin (jaxb/jax-ws) to compile this to Java classes. To avoid the name clashes, we have formerly used the option **-AutoNameResolution**.
However, we have found that this leads to unexpected results, where on some machines one 
class gets renamed to ResetPasswordResponse2.java, while on other machines the **other** class is renamed.
This makes collaborative development very difficult, and also gives us worries for the future (what if it won't compile correctly on Jenkins at some point?)

**Question:**
I am looking for a way to manually determine how the translation/renaming should take place.

- I am told that simply changing the names in the WSDL will not work, because the xml naming annotations in the Java files are of importance.
- I have also looked into binding files or inline binding statements, but cannot get it to work. The documentation at http://wiki.netbeans.org/WsdlCustomizer#Class_Customization seems to imply that name changes are only possible for "wsdl:portType, wsdl:fault, soap:headerfault, and wsdl:server", which indicates I might be trying to do something that is simply impossible.

Are jaxb/jax-ws bindings a possible solution? Are there other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this question and answer:

> [JAXB Binding for XSD outside WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687186/jaxb-binding-for-xsd-outside-wsdl)

In short, you can use so-called binding files to customize names.

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsdschema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='ResetPasswordResponse']">
            <jxb:class name="ResetPasswordResponseType"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

You may be interested in [`jaxb:nameXmlTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html):

> [Issue with JAXB: nameXmlTransform typeName prefix not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685003/issue-with-jaxb-namexmltransform-typename-prefix-not-working)

This would allow you to customize type or element naming rules globally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
         <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type"/>
            <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
         </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Credits go to [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21685303/303810).

Comment: Thank you, Lexicore.

As it turns out, my main problem was in the namespace/schemalocation defined in my external binding file. I have now managed to get the
binding file properly tied to the wsdl.
Your first example of classname customization encouraged me to try again to get that solution to work, and the final result is indeed very similar to your code.

However, the option for global renaming is also highly interesting, and might avoid a lot of trouble for other people (where even more naming conflicts exist or might arise in future versions of their wsdl).

Comment: What is this two pieces? schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema". I dont see anything like that in my wsdl